# Terraform helm chart set value tolerations

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm trying to pass toleration values into helm using terraform. But I have got different error messages.

Default values of the [chart are here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/victoriametrics/victoria-metrics-cluster?modal=values&path=vmstorage.tolerations).

```yaml
...
  tolerations:
    []
...
```

I use this code.

```
locals {
  victoria_tolerations = [{ "key" : "k8s-app", "operator" : "Equal", "value" : "grafana", "effect" : "NoSchedule" }]
}


resource "helm_release" "victoria_metrics" {
  name        = var.vm_release_name
  chart       = var.vm_chart
  repository  = var.vm_chart_repository_url
  version     = var.vm_chart_version
  namespace   = local.namespace_victoria
  max_history = var.max_history

set {
    name  = "vmselect.tolerations"
    value = jsonencode(local.victoria_tolerations)
  }
}
```

And have got the error message:

```
Error: failed parsing key "vmselect.tolerations" with value [{"effect":"NoSchedule","key":"k8s-app","operator":"Equal","value":"grafana"}], key "\"key\":\"k8s-app\"" has no value (cannot end with ,)
```

If I use this variable

```
victoria_tolerations = <<EOF
      - key: k8s-app
        operator: Equal
        value: grafana
        effect: NoSchedule
    EOF
```

I have got this error:

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.tolerations): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec.tolerations: got "string", expected "array"
```

P.S.
Also, I tried to pass as `values`. This doesn't work in this case.

```
locals {
  victoria_values = {
    "tolerations" : [
      {
        "key" : "k8s-app",
        "operator" : "Equal",
        "value" : "grafana",
        "effect" : "NoSchedule"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
resource "helm_release" "victoria_metrics" {
  name        = var.vm_release_name
  ...
  values = [
    yamlencode(local.victoria_values)
  ]
}
```

Comment: The way you do that with yamlencode and using the values key is actually correct. I doubt you get the same error. If you get another one please post it. Apart from that I would use json as its more solid `values = [jsonencode(local.victoria_values)]`

Answer (score 3):

Try **dynamic** block

```
dynamic "toleration" {
            for_each = var.tolerations
            content {
              key      = toleration.value["key"]
              operator = toleration.value["operator"]
              value    = toleration.value["value"]
              effect   = toleration.value["effect"]
            }
          }
```

**var** file

```
variable "tolerations" {
  type        = list(map(string))
  default     = []
  description = "Tolerations to apply to deployment"
}
```

**arg**

```
tolerations = [
    {
      key      = "node.kubernetes.io/role",
      operator = "Equal",
      value    = "true",
      effect   = "NoSchedule"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The possible but may not so elegant solution is:

```
resource "helm_release" "victoria_metrics" {
  name        = var.vm_release_name
  chart       = var.vm_chart
  repository  = var.vm_chart_repository_url
  version     = var.vm_chart_version
  namespace   = local.namespace_victoria
  max_history = var.max_history

  dynamic "set" {
    for_each = {
      "rbac.create" = true

      "vminsert.tolerations[0].key"      = "k8s-app"
      "vminsert.tolerations[0].value"    = "grafana"
      "vminsert.tolerations[0].operator" = "Equal"
      "vminsert.tolerations[0].effect"   = "NoSchedule"

      "vmselect.tolerations[0].key"      = "k8s-app"
      "vmselect.tolerations[0].value"    = "grafana"
      "vmselect.tolerations[0].operator" = "Equal"
      "vmselect.tolerations[0].effect"   = "NoSchedule"

      "vmstorage.tolerations[0].key"      = "k8s-app"
      "vmstorage.tolerations[0].value"    = "grafana"
      "vmstorage.tolerations[0].operator" = "Equal"
      "vmstorage.tolerations[0].effect"   = "NoSchedule"

    }
    content {
      name  = set.key
      value = set.value
    }
  }

  values = [
    yamlencode(local.victoria_values)
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to  @Rostyslav Malenko's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71129448/17546520) but without `dynamic` `for_each` loops.

```
resource "helm_release" "victoria_metrics" {
  name        = var.vm_release_name
  chart       = var.vm_chart
  repository  = var.vm_chart_repository_url
  version     = var.vm_chart_version
  namespace   = local.namespace_victoria
  max_history = var.max_history


  set {
    name = "vmselect.tolerations[0].key"
    value= "k8s-app"
  }
  set {
    name = "vmselect.tolerations[0].value"
    value= "grafana"
  }
  set {
    name = "vmselect.tolerations[0].operator"
    value= "Equal"
  }
  set {
    name = "vmselect.tolerations[0].effect"
    value= "NoSchedule"
  }
```